# Web Service fails to start: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a web service that will not run anymore. It previously had the 64-bit version installed, but now the 32-bit is installed. However, it seems that it is looking for a 64-bit version of the ChilkatDotNet2.dll, which is strange. The version that was installed by the MSI-package is X86.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Sipp\Market Server\bin>asminfo.exe
>   ChilkatDotNet2.dll ChilkatDotNet2, Version=9.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09b d | X86

I enabled FusionLog and it gave the following output:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'ChilkatDotNet2' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = SF\sonsupport LOG: DisplayName = ChilkatDotNet2  (Partial) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Sipp/Market Server/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Sipp\Market Server\bin Calling
>   assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sipp\Market
>   Server\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/server/b8e4736f/d41d574d/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/server/b8e4736f/d41d574d/ChilkatDotNet2/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Sipp/Market Server/bin/ChilkatDotNet2.DLL. ERR: Failed to
>   complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ChilkatDotNet2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +416
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +166    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +190
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ChilkatDotNet2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11241896
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +388    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +232
>   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +48
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +210
>   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory
>   vdir) +191
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory
>   vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +54
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) +295
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile) +476
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +116
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String
>   virtualPath) +39
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +202
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +33
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +46
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +654
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/server/service.svc' cannot
>   be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet2' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format..]
>   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +15778592
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +15698937
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, Boolean flowContext) +265
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +227
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Comment: Have you [contacted the supplier](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/support.asp) of the library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIS > Application pools > your application pool > Advanced settings > set `Enable 32bit application` to true.

Comment: I was getting this error after deploying a service to the live servers, and it was a real pain!  This led me directly to the thing that solved it!  Thank you!!!